# Wordpress plugin menu issue

Tags: wordpress

I am building a wordpress plugin with the boilerplate framework (https://wppb.me/). That all works fine. I have an annoying issues which I cannot solve.

the boilerplate makes per object one php file. In this php file all funtionality for the object is arranged. Pages, lists, validations etc.

Example in the file for contact there is a method contactlog_menu:
Object: contact

```
 public function contactlog_menu()
 {
   add_submenu_page('plugin-options',  __('plugin', 'plugin'),  __('am_contactlogs', 'plugin'), 'manage_options', 'contactlogs',  array($this, 'plugin_contactlogs_page_handler'));
   add_submenu_page('contactlogs', __('New contactlog', 'plugin'), __('Add new b', 'plugin'), 'activate_plugins', 'contactlogs_form', array($this, 'plugin_contactlogs_form_page_handler'));
 }
```

Now it shows a menu option in the left menu of wordpress. I would like to remove this menu option and create a hyperlink on the dashboardpage to this page. If i remove the lines wordpress is telling me i have no permission to view the page. what am i missing here

So i want to remove the menu item but want to page to be accessible as a link on another page. Otherwise my menu will become very large :-).

I hope it is understandable, otherwise please ask..

Answer (score 0):

If you use `null` for the parent_slug parameter the page won't show up in the menu.

```
add_submenu_page(
    null,
    'My Custom Submenu Page',
    'My Custom Submenu Page',
    'manage_options',
    'my-custom-submenu-page',
    'callback_function' );
```

The page will be accessible via any parent slug, as long as it exists:

- `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page`
- `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page`
- `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/index.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page`
- ...

Or no parent slug at all (same effect as if you'd use `index.php`):

- `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/?page=my-custom-submenu-page`

But it's probably best to use `admin.php` for your hyperlinks (the menu item that belongs to the slug you use will be active - if you use `admin.php` no menu item will be active):

- `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page`